# Error in Shifrin Multivariable Mathematics (Exercise 7.1.10)

Tags: calculus, integration

I finished the proof for the exercise a while ago, but I'm still confused about something in the "hint". Shifrin says to "Show that covering the dividing hyperplanes (of total area $A$) requires at most volume $A\delta/\sqrt{n}$." Why wouldn't the maximum required volume just be $A\delta$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to MSE.  Since most people here won't have the textbook on hand, it's probably better to post the details of the statement with your question. At any rate, yes, this is a typo that was corrected in the second printing. The problem should state "requires at most volume $2A\delta$." (The $2$ comes in to cover the case that the partition is chosen so that the dividing hyperplanes are included.) By the way, [here](https://math.franklin.uga.edu/sites/default/files/inline-files/Multivariable_Errors.pdf) is the list of errata for the book.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Where can the second printing be found?